# Maxima and Minima question subscripts and differentiation?

Tags: calculus

You are given the numbers n numbers a1, a2, a3,.... an consider the function

D(x) = "start with n=1 and finish at n=n" --> (x - a(subscript k) )^2

Show that D is a minimum when x is the average of a1, a2, an

I'd post what i'd think but i need some help where to start. It's a bit confusing to what i learnt.

To get a minimum from my understanding is i need to find a stationary point
D'(x) = 0 and D''(x) > 0

But how do i differentiate this think with the a subscript ak?
T1 = (x-1)^2, T2 = (x-2)^2, .... Tn= (x-n)^2

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that $D(x)$ is the **sum of all the terms** $(x-a_k)^2$, that is,
$$D(x)=(x-a_1)^2+(x-a_2)^2+\cdots+(x-a_n)^2\ .$$
Since all the $a_k$ are constants, we have
$$D'(x)=2(x-a_1)+2(x-a_2)+\cdots+2(x-a_n)\ ;$$
if this is zero then dividing by $2$ gives
$$(x-a_1)+(x-a_2)+\cdots+(x-a_n)=0\ ,$$
that is,
$$nx=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n\ ,$$
so $x$ is the average of $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$.  I will leave it for you to explain why $D''(x)>0$.

Comment: so D''(x) 1*(x-an)^0*1 = 1

Comment: so D''(x) 1*(x-an)^0*1 = 1
since D''(x) can only be larger than 1 so there is a minimum. 

And there is (x-an)=0 when x=an so when the average value, an, is equal x then D is stationary point where D will always be a minimum due to a constantly positive value.